# Improper p-value for Kruskal Wallis test; possibly related to NA values?

Tags: r, na, p-value

I was trying to perform a Kruskal-Wallis test between two columns in a dataframe when I saw that, if I compare a column to itself, I do not get a p-value of 1:

```
controlvcontrol<- kruskal.test(neurite.5RGD[,1], neurite.5RGD[,1], na.rm=TRUE)  
controlvcontrol$p.value
[1] 7.967453e-99
```

Same thing happens if I compare two different columns that hold identical data:

```
(1:length(neurite.5RGD[,1]))[which((neurite.5RGD[,1]-neurite.5RGD[,3])!=0)]
integer(0)

> controlvBDNF<- kruskal.test(neurite.5RGD[,1], neurite.5RGD[,3], na.rm=T)
> controlvBDNF$p.value
[1] 7.967453e-99
```

I figured this was due to the NA values in the columns, so I tried a simple example:

```
> x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4,5, NA, NA)
> y <-  c(1, 2, 3, 4,5, NA, NA)
> krus <- kruskal.test(x,y, na.rm = TRUE)
> krus$p.value
[1] 0.4060058
> ttest <- t.test(x,y, na.rm=T)
> ttest$p.value
[1] 1
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?